# Android lock task mode: how to enable quick settings menu?

Tags: android, locking, task, settings, mode

i'm developing a kiosk android app that launch a single app specified by package name. In task mode i can't use the quick settings menu so i need to enable it. I prefer to enable it by first app (kiosk launcher) and not by the launched app because i will be able to open any app without any restriction.
I'm searching a way for Setting.ACTION_QUICK_LAUNCH_SETTINGS without success.

Thank you